# knockout with side page causing You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, knockout-3.0

I am building a SPA using knockoutJs. The problem I am facing is that I have a side bar page with several anchor links which will load different pages as per code snippet below

```
 $('div#list a').click(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    if (page == "new") {
        $('#container').load('application/application.jsp', function(data){
            //return false;
        });
        return false;
    } else if (page == "dashboard") {
        $('#container').load('dashboard/dashboard.jsp', function(data){
            //return false;
        });
        return false;
    }
 });
```

For each page, I am loading the corresponding html and js. For instance, where page is new in the example above, the html is as follows

```
<form>......fields are there</form><script src="application/application.js"></script>
```

My Js file is as per below:

```
var ApplicationForm = function () {
/* add members here */
/* the model */
var app = {
    nid: ko.observable(),
    lastName: "",
    firstName: "",
    address: "",
};

var addEmployment = function() {
};

var removeEmployment = function(params) {
};

var init = function () {
    /* add code to initialise this module */
    ko.applyBindings(ApplicationForm);
};

/* form submission */
var submit = function () {
    console.log(ko.toJSON(app ));
};

/**
 * subscribe to checkbox isdead and if false, clear the values
 */
app.isDead.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    //when false, clear all values
     if (!newValue) {
          //
     }
});

/* execute the init function when the DOM is ready */
$(init);

return {
    /* add members that will be exposed publicly */
    submit: submit,
    application: app,
    add: addEmployment,
    remove: removeEmployment
};
```

}();

Some details are omitted. The problem is everytime I click on a side link page, it will load the corresponding and JS as well and it is giving the error **You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element** since I am calling applyBindings multiple times.

Can someone advise me on how I should design my page so that I do not get this error?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't tell from your code where applyBindings is being called the second time. Is it that each page calls it in its init function after being loaded so the second time you click a link is when you get the error?

Comment: @JasonSpake yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're reusing the same element each time you'll need to clear the previous bindings before applying the new ones. This can be done with `ko.cleanNode(element);`

It might work to put it at the top of your switching function like so, but I can't tell for sure based on the available code posted.

```
$('div#list a').click(function(){
    ko.cleanNode($('#container')[0]);
    ...
```

You might also need to change your applyBindings to only target that same element depending on where else you're using bindings outside of that element.

```
ko.applyBindings(ApplicationForm, $('#container')[0]);
```

Comment: @ashley in what way does it not work? It might just need a little tweaking

Comment: @ashley Did you try changing your applyBindings to only apply to the container element as well? `ko.applyBindings(ApplicationForm, $('#container')[0]);`

Comment: wow. that just works. I was just doing ko.applyBindings(ApplicationForm). Is what I am doing is correct or is there a better way to structure the html and js files? Thanks a lot

Comment: @ashley What you were doing before applies bindings globally which might be exactly what you want if you have other bindings outside of the container element. It just depends on how the rest of your code works. Another approach might be to apply bindings once globally, and use observables to swap the container's contents using template bindings for example, but what you have is fine